# What's the proper way to replace `<a>` using Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make HTML elements clickable using Javascript. Here's what I have:

```
<div class="link">
<a href="http://example.com">
</div>

<script>
$('.link').click(function(){
  if(link=$(this).find('a').attr('href'))
    window.location.href=link;
});
</script>
```

This works, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do that if `href` is already specified in the anchor tag?

Comment: @Nirmal Because he wants the entire div to be clickable

Comment: Note that part of an anchor tag's built-in behaviour is to allow a "click" via the keyboard (i.e., when the link has focus and you press enter), so if you replace your anchors with divs this functionality will break and your page will not meet accessibility standards. Regarding your code, you should declare `link` with `var` or it will be a global variable.

Comment: @ChristianVarga: Oh good, I overlooked the `link` class given to the div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While your example works, it is neither semantic nor clean. You can't right click the div to copy the link location or open in new tab, or middle click it etc. There's nothing stopping you from setting an anchor to `display: block` to act like a div and then putting all sorts of elements inside the `a` tag itself. That's the semantic way to do it - let the browser handle the native function of a link.

Answer (score 2):

[Starting with HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), you may simply wrap your flow content within your anchor tag.

```
<a href="http://example.com/">
  <div class="special">
    <img src="http://example.com/news.jpg" alt="Great Picture" />
    <p>Great News! This whole section is clickable!</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

This allows for the functionality you want without using clunky JavaScript code, and doesn't break browser gestures (middle click for new tab).

A few rules however apply in order to stick to the HTML5 standard:

- The parent tag of your `<a>` must allow for *flow content*. The anchor tag in HTML5 has a *transparent* content model, meaning that it adopts the model of its parent.
- You may not place any interactive content (e.g. buttons or other links) within your anchor tag.

Note that this works in all browsers, including Internet Explorer 6. However, make sure you set the `display` style of your `<a>` tag to either `block` or `inline-block` depending on the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the html the best thing to do is to just change the div to an a, then you can make the a "display: block" so it is a block element like the div.

Answer (score 1):

You can also wrap the `div` in `anchor` tag i.e `<a href="#">Div goes here</a>`. In this way u get wat u want. No more styling and javascript needed :)

Answer (score -1):

If HTML5 is ok you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').click(function(e){
        window.location.href = $(this).data('link');
    });
});
</script>
<div class="link" data-link="http://example.com">My Link</div>
```

Comment: -1: [In HTML5, you can also simply do `<a href="http://example.com/"><div>My Link</div></a>`.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element). All browsers (including IE6) support it (some, like IE6, support it by accident). *"The `<a>` element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)."*

Comment: His original inquiry mentioned a JS solution so i wanted to give a JS answer.  I would never do it that way myself.  But I can understand the ding...

Comment: [His question was never edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9338828/revisions). His original query was and still is "I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this".

Comment: True, but it starts off "I want to make HTML elements clickable using Javascript."... then at the end he asks "This works, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.".  To me that reads as if he is asking specifically for a better way to do it in JS.